# How to create responsive DIV

Tags: css, html, scale

Can anyone help me to write some CSS code, so my accordion will be responsive and stay in the same place just like on a screenshot below:

[image]

My image is already have "scale-with-grid" tag, so the only thing left to do is to make accordion div fit under it.

Site **[link here](http://podstrigis.com/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82/)**

Comment: Using % width doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know how to do it myself. I need my div container to stay like on these screenshots: 1) full-width page http://i.imgur.com/OM9vMQm.jpg 2) mobile http://i.imgur.com/ZB5FD3T.jpg  Hopyfully it's more clear now. I would reall appreciate If anybody can help me to code this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your div `column one-second` you need to overide the skelton.css width set.

You can use a selector like `.container div.one-second`, I think it will do the job.

the use percent value, example :

```
.container div.one-second{
    width : 50%;
    margin-left : 50%;
}
```

That will make you cell width usin 50% of the page with the left border positionned at 50% (middle) of you page. Adjust those value depending on your image.

In theories, the `margin-left` value should be equal to the portion the girl arm is taking.

Comment: Thanks! That's not exactly what I wanted (my accordion cuts when I tighten up browser window), but helped me a lot.

Comment: There is probly media queries modifying some rules. Are you used with Firebug or chrome developement tools?

Comment: I've managed to fix it completely by adding "min-width: 160px" tag. God bless helpful people on stackoverflow! =)

Comment: Ahah glad it worked ! :P

Answer (score 0):

The box wont move like this:

**css**

```
  position:absolute;
  margin-left: px;
```